# Why does $\cos(\pi x)$ approach $0^-$, as $x\to{\frac{1}2}^-$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

[image]

In problem 220, I understand the rest of the solution except that I don't know why $\cos(\pi x)$ approaches to $0$ from the left, making the solution $-\infty$. I have seen a few problems like this, where it doesn't make sense to me with the unit circle definition. Thank you!

Comment: As $x\to 0.5+$, we have $\pi x \to (\pi/2)+$.  Now look at the graph of cosine.  It is zero at $\pi/2$, and negative just to the right of $\pi/2$.  Hence $\cos(\pi x)\to 0-$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually approaching from the right. When it says ${\frac12}^+$ is means you approach $1/2$ from the right, that is with values grater than $1/2$. So you are approaching $\pi/2$ from the right; and to the right of $\pi/2$ the cosine is negative; so your denominator goes to zero from the left (i.e., with negative numbers) and so the quotient goes to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5B+Cos%5BPi+x%5D,+%7Bx,0,1%7D%5D)'s a plot of $\cos(\pi x)$.

We know that $\cos\left( \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 0$.  When we are just to the right of 1/2, $\cos(\pi x)$ is a very small negative number.  A finite, positive, non-zero number $\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x}\right)$ divided by a very small negative number gives you a very large negative number.  So, as that "very small negative number" goes to zero, your result will go to negative infinity.